# What is the query binding marker for CURRENT_DATE when using mysqli prepared statements?

Tags: php, mysqli

So I've finished building a question and answer site and am now trying to defend it against SQL injection but having problems with CURRENT_DATE.  I want to insert current date with the question into db but what binding marker would that be?  "s" for string is not working?

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "questions87";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
session_start();
$question = $_POST["question"];


$uname = $_SESSION['username'];

$qa_email =$_SESSION['email'];

// prepare and bind
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO login (username, username, q_date, qa_email) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("ssss", $question, $uname, CURRENT_DATE, $qa_email);



$stmt->execute();

if ($stmt) {echo "Thank you ". $uname . " Your question has been submitted " . "<br>";}
 else {echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);}


$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Just to explain.. PHP understands that you are passing a constant that was never defined. If you were to insert a date(time) using a php function like `$someDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',time());` you would indeed need to use "s".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use simple mysql function [`NOW()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) and remove placeholder for `q_date`:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO login (username, username, q_date, qa_email) VALUES (?, ?, NOW(), ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $question, $uname, $qa_email);
```

Btw, I noticed, you have field `username` twice in this query. I suppose one of the occurences should be replaced with some other field.

Comment: Thanks I think you're right but any idea why I'm getting this error when I run it? "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ask/subq.php:24 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ask/subq.php on line 24"  Line 24 is: $stmt->bind_param("sss", $question, $uname, $qa_email);

Comment: This happens because `prepare` failed to prepare a query. Use [`mysqil_error`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) to get detail error text.

Comment: @do734 This is a different error. If someone helps you solve the problem you posted about, please give that person credit first.  Anyway, what you're seeing is likely because `$conn->prepare` failed, so `$stmt` is `FALSE` instead of a prepared statement. Check for errors before using `$stmt` and look at the error details. `if(!$stmt) die(mysqli_error($conn))`

Comment: thanks,  stackoverflow says I need to wait a few mins to accept this answer? I am definitely going to give @u_mulder credit don't worry.

Comment: "you cannot accept answer in 2 minutes" pop's up every time I try to accept the answer?

Comment: One thing to watch out when getting the date from the DB, is that the settings for the default timezone are separate of those for PHP, so you could have a database with a different idea of what NOW is then php's date